# Dúvida sobre alterar dados em arrays em java

Tags: java, array

Tenho um array da classe Pessoa chamado vetor.

Já povoei o vetor com as instancias de pessoas nomeadas de `p1`.

Minha dúvida consiste em saber como alterar o valor de `p1` quando está dentro do *array*:

Exemplo:

Array de pessoa chamado vetor:

```
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa();
vetor.add(p1);
```

Para pegar o nome por exemplo seria:

```
vetor.get(posicao).getNome();
```

e funciona perfeitamente.

Agora como faço para Setar o nome?

Tentei

```
vetor.set(posicao).setNome();
```

e não funciona.

Comment: Poderia postar como foi criado o array?
você já tentou vetor.get(posição).setNome()?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo seu código parece que você esta usando uma List, então você pode fazer assim:

O método **get(<>)** retorna o objeto atrelado com o respectivo índice:

```
//Criação da List
List<Pessoa> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new Pessoa());

//Recupera o valor
Pessoa p1 = list.get(0);

//Altera o valor
p1.setNome("Novo nome.");

//Exibição do conteudo
list.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getNome()));
```